# Unable to connect Automation Anywhere(v11.3) Client to a AA (v11.3) Control Room installed on an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, automationanywhere

I am creating a POC for a client where Automation Anywhere Control Room is installed on an EC2 instance and the AAE Client is installed locally. The client has to connect to the Control Room. I am currently using v11.3.0 of Automation Anywhere (both control room and client are of the same version). My problem is that I am unable to connect to the control room. If I use RDP, I am able to connect to the EC2 instance and work on it. I am having a problem connecting the client. Can anyone please guide me on this? I have been at this for quite some time now.

Pallavi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to open port 80/8080/443 on your security group on AWS.

docs ref: https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v2019/page/enterprise-cloud/topics/deployment-planning/on-prem-install/cloud-firewall-rules.html

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the EC2 Instance Security Groups if the necessary ports have been opened for communication. I have added the appropriate official documentation for your reference. [Automation Anywhere Firewall Link](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/enterprise/topics/aae-architecture-implementation/firewall-rules.html)